# log4net NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter being reported multiple times

Tags: wpf, wcf, nhibernate, log4net

I've been working on configuring my log4net and noticed something interesting when I'm logging nHibernate exceptions.

NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher

NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter

NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter

NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter

For each exception I get 3 of the ADO with the exact same message.

This hasn't been a problem while I was logging to a rolling file, but now that I'm setting up SMTP I'd rather not get 4 emails per error.

I'm not sure if this is something I can configure to turn off in log4net or nhibernate

Any help would be...we'll...helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can disable the ADOExceptionReporter logger if it just repeats the exception

```
<logger name="NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter">
  <level value="OFF" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's not the name of the logger, that's the namespace the error is happening in.  Am I missing something?

Comment: the logger name is normaly equal the class name it is created in as in here. ADOExceptionReporter is the standard sqlexception converter which also logs it. just disable the logging there. its unlikly that it throws exceptions itself

Comment: as you can see in the source code here https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Util/ADOExceptionReporter.cs it logs 3 times for debug, warn, error. And the error is pratically the same as in the code running the exception in your application so for me is right to disable it all.